# ANDROID SAX Parser issue

Tags: android, saxparser

Since I am new to java programming, I need a bit of help with this. I stuck on this one issue and can't continue until I get this to work.

I am trying to make a string from that includes a preference int. I saved the data and can display the int (just sample code):

```
SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    list.setText(prefs.getString("list", "22"));
```

now, I have a xml parser  that is pulling a url correctly as a static string:

`public static String feedUrl = String.format("http://www.freshpointmarketing.com/iphone/objects/XML/AND.php?ID=%d", 22);`

Works great...

now my issue......

I need to have the preference "int" become the variable in the string, thus making it not static.

```
static SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

static int myVariable = prefs.getInt("list1", 22);

public static String feedUrl = String.format("http://www.freshpointmarketing.com/iphone/objects/XML/AND.php?ID=%d", myVariable);
```

If I take out all static references, I get an error on this:

```
    private void loadFeed(ParserType type){
    try{
        FeedParser parser = FeedParserFactory.getParser(type);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        messages = parser.parse();
        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        Log.i("AndroidNews", "Parser duration=" + duration);
        String xml = writeXml();
        Log.i("AndroidNews", xml);
        List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
        for (Message msg : messages){
            titles.add(msg.getTitle());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,titles);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Throwable t){
        Log.e("AndroidNews",t.getMessage(),t);
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your use of statics here is pretty inappropriate.  Better to do this within your Activity lifecycle, such as in onCreate.  It's a little hard to see what's going on with the code you posted, but try passing down the url through the application to the place you actually use it, and get rid of all the statics.